# How do you use "?" with sqlite statements in an executeQuery method?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I assume that you can include "?" in your sqlite statement, provided in the "executeQuery" method, you pass additional arguments corresponding to each "?". But when I put this to practice, the results are not consistent.

This statement works:

```
SELECT * FROM answers WHERE test_id = ? and question_id = ?
```

with this method

```
FMResultSet * answer = [[UIApp database] executeQuery:[Queries getTheAnswer], l, n];
```

The following statement crashes the program when I include a `"?"`

```
SELECT * FROM questions where test_id = ? ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT ?
FMResultSet * set = [[UIApp database] executeQuery:[Queries randomNumberOfVerses], selectedTests, numRounds];
```

But works fine when I hardcode a value in.

```
SELECT * FROM questions where test_id = 5 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT ?
FMResultSet * set = [[UIApp database] executeQuery:[Queries randomNumberOfVerses], numRounds];
```

Any suggestions since I don't want to hardcode values in? All variable used as arguments are of type NSNumber*

Comment: Format code by selection or indenting by 4 spaces. Post the code for `executeQuery`. Something seems incorrect in your binding.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I know what you mean by post the code for executeQuery. I assumed that I was just using the default method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the iPhone or Objective C, but usually `?` arguments are used for prepared statements, rather than "immediate mode" queries.

In the [SQLite C API](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html), the functions you're interested in are called `sqlite3_prepare*()`.

If you can figure out what the Objective C mapping is for those, you should be able make some progress.

Edit:

I almost forgot the part that actually answers your question...

Once you have a prepared statement, use the [`sqlite3_bind*()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) functions to give values to the query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

While `WHERE` clauses can include bind-parameters, the LIMIT argument cannot.  It has to be an integer literal. See the [SQLite Syntax Diagram](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html).

Given that, I'm not sure why your last one is working.  It should be fine if you hardcode the LIMIT argument, leaving the `test_id = ?`, but it shouldn't work when you use ? for the LIMIT.